# from jquery to javascript autoscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone tell me what this code would look like if it was written only using vanilla javascript? I'm using some snippets to "convert" but it doesn't seem to work, thanks to anyone who makes it available

```
$(".toggle").on("click", function () {
    $(".container").toggleClass("microsoft");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let toggle = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle');

toggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let container = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
    container.classList.toggle('microsoft');
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.